# Does miniconda installation affect standard python installation?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, miniconda

I had first installed python using the standard python distribution available on their official website and I would be using pip to install all necessary packages.
However, now I wish to use miniconda, since it is a better choice for data science.
But, it installs python along with It and I don't want to disturb my earlier setup of pip+Python.
Will installing miniconda affect my python installation.
Is there a way of installing it without disturbing the python installation?
I am on a Windows operating system.

Comment: Look into virtualenvs. It allows you to have different libraries with different versions of Python on the same computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely install Anaconada (or Miniconda) on top of other Python installations. It goes into a completely different folder on your local disk. But leave the default installation options on default, especially don't add Python to your path.

The important thing is that you activate your environment before you use it via

```
conda activate
```

and then start Python from there (or let your IDE do that for you).

```
(base)> python
```

Without activatation conda doesn't work and calling python from the command prompt will start your 'standard installation' again.

The advantage of Anaconda is that it guarantees maximumum consistency for the 'scientific stack' and in case you are still missing some 3rd party packages you can always install them aditionally via `pip install' into an activated conda environment.